# Part of sculpture is low poly

Tags: sculpting, polycount

As you can see the head of the sculpture is high poly. But the lower part is low poly. I tried smoothing it out but it stays like this.

Does anyone know what I can do about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This, if it was an imported model, could have been sculpted with dyntopia sculpting. It may have also been modeled in edit mode, instead of sculpting. In this case, the best way to achieve a nice-looking result would be to subdivide, or to save memory, subdivide those faces.

Comment: It wasn't imported. I created it in sculpt mode.

Comment: Then subdivide.